# yii2 kartik switch input type radio button get value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, yii2

I use the yii2 kartik switch input with the type radio and i want to get the value of the selected option in javascript (specially in a JsExpression), here is my code :

```
        $model->orientation = 'Portrait';
        echo $form->field($model, 'orientation')->widget(SwitchInput::classname(), [
            'name' => 'information_orientation',
            'type' => SwitchInput::RADIO,
            'value' => 'Portrait',
            'items' => [
                ['label' => 'Portrait&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp', 'value' => 'Portrait'],
                ['label' => 'Paysage&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp', 'value' => 'Paysage'],
            ],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'onText' => 'Oui',
                'offText' => 'Non',
                'onColor' => 'success',
                'offColor' => 'danger',
                'size' => 'mini'
            ],
            'labelOptions' => ['style' => 'font-size: 13px'],
        ]);
```

I have tried :

```
$([name='information-orientation']).val()
```

But it returned an undifined value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SwitchInput` class [does not care](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base/blob/bed522a930746e16391e4b207b7b2d82cc0ebab7/InputWidget.php#L210) about the name property you give it
according to their docs, you need to wrap `name` in a `options` array

```
echo $form->field($model, 'orientation')
    ->widget(SwitchInput::classname(), [
        'options' => ['name' => 'information_orientation'],
        'type' => SwitchInput::RADIO,
 ....
```

from [docs](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/switchinput):

> `options`: *array* the HTML attributes for the widget input tag.

**edit:**
you can then use the following

```
// to get value:
$("[name='information_orientation']").val()

// to check if the switch is or on off
$("[name='information_orientation']").prop('checked')
```

Comment: thanks, now how can i get the value of the selected option?

Comment: @BlackstarMC97 your initial method of selecting the input was almost correct (dash in selector and underscore in name) .. updated the answer with examples

Comment: great it works, i use $(\"[name='information_orientation']:checked\").val() and it returns me the selected value, thanks for your help, you saved my day

Comment: @BlackstarMC97, happy to help. do get into the habit of accepting/voting useful answers. :)